# just echo price from this tag

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

how can i echo just the salesPrice without creating a pricediv? I have tried echo salesPrice but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php echo "<span  class='priceColor2'>" . $this->currencyDisplay->createPriceDiv ('salesPrice', '', $this->cart->pricesUnformatted, FALSE) . "</span>"  ?>
```

the code currently echos the price in a separate div like this:

```
<span  class='priceColor2'><div class="PricesalesPrice" style="display : block;" ><span class="PricesalesPrice" >£20.00</span></div></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
<?php echo "<span  class='priceColor2'>" . strip_tags($this->currencyDisplay->createPriceDiv ('salesPrice', '', $this->cart->pricesUnformatted, FALSE)) . "</span>"  ?>
```